# "Expected a statement" error in embedded C

Tags: c, arm, keil, arm7

I'm getting error like "expected an statement"

my code is as follows

```
#define IN_Tamper    0X00001000     /*P2.12 = EINT2*/
#define DIR_IN_Tamper    { FIO2DIR &= ~0X00001000 ; } 

/* main */
DIR_IN_Tamper(); 
if(((IN_Tamper >> 12) & 0x01) == 1)
            BUZZER_ON();
         else
            BUZZER_OFF();
```

I'm getting error saying

1. Expected an statement for DIR_IN_Tamper();
2. expected a statement for the else part.....

Comment: or defined like: `#define DIR_IN_Tamper(FIO2DIR)    { FIO2DIR &= ~0X00001000 ; }`; and call like `DIR_IN_Tamper(FIO2DIR);` what is `FIO2DIR` ?

Comment: #define DIR_IN_Tamper  { FIO2DIR &= ~0X00001000 ; } like this......

Comment: No I mean what is `FIO2DIR` ? if its macro then consider @phihag's answer. If its variable you wants to pass  then defined like macro function as I suggested.

Comment: FIO2DIR is ARM7's key word...

Comment: then Consider @phihag's answer, One think he didn't explain  is that in macro definitional `{}` is used because programmer wants to give complete statement (including `;`). If at the time of macro calling,  suppose use  forgets `;` then it will not cause any error.

Comment: lastly I have removed () from every where n its working fine..

thank you all..

Answer (score 7):

The C preprocessor is (at least in the way you use it) just a simple search-and-replace, so you're effectively running

```
/* main */
{ FIO2DIR &= ~0X00001000 ; } ();
```

This doesn't make any sense. Remove the parentheses in the line

```
DIR_IN_Tamper();
```

For `BUZZER_ON` and `BUZZER_OFF`, you want to remove the parentheses as well. If the macro isn't enclosed in curly braces, you also want to add those, like

```
if(((IN_Tamper >> 12) & 0x01) == 1) {
    BUZZER_ON
} else {
    BUZZER_OFF
}
```

Comment: for BUZZER_ON/OFF I have used macro

Comment: like 
#define DIR_BUZ()  FIO0DIR |= 0x10000000 ;  //DIRECTION FOR BUZ PIn P0.28
#define B_BUZ_E(X) {(X==SET)? (FIO0SET |= PINO_BUZ) : (FIO0CLR |= PINO_BUZ) ;} 

#define BUZZER_ON()   { DIR_BUZ(); B_BUZ_E(1); }  
     
#define BUZZER_OFF()  { DIR_BUZ(); B_BUZ_E(0); }

Answer (score 2):

`DIR_IN_Tamper` is defined as `{ FIO2DIR &= ~0X00001000 ; }`, therefore when the preprocessor parses your code, this line

```
DIR_IN_Tamper();
```

is converted into

```
{ FIO2DIR &= ~0X00001000 ; }()
```

Which is clearly not correct.  Not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve, but removing the parentheses will eliminate the syntax error:

```
DIR_IN_Tamper
```

Further to it, I suspect you have similar issues with `BUZZER_ON` and `BUZZER_OFF`.

Comment: Shouldn't `DIR_IN_Tamper` rather be defined as a function-like macro?

Comment: Maybe it should but I see the question unclear in terms of what he exactly wants to do

Comment: @undur_gongor Maybe it should be, but, as KiaMorot pointed out, it's rather unclear from the question what the OP is trying to do.  I showed one way to syntax errors.

Comment: if I remove {} it gives error 
error:  #109: expression must have (pointer-to-) function type

Comment: @user2571585: You have to remove the normal parentheses (`()`), not the curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `DIR_IN_Tamper` like a function, you need a function-like macro:

```
#define DIR_IN_Tamper()    { FIO2DIR &= ~0X00001000 ; }
```

Then, a better way to do it is:

```
#define DIR_IN_Tamper()    do { FIO2DIR &= ~0X00001000 ; } while(0)
```

... but that's a different story.

Comment: Yes, it is a macro. But you try to "invoke" it like a function (with `()`). Therefore you need a function-like macro.

Comment: macro of BUZZER_OFF is as follows-

Comment: #define BUZZER_OFF() { DIR_BUZ(); B_BUZ_E(0); }

Comment: do I need to remove () or {} here also..??
its not single statement but.

Comment: First and foremost, you should add the definitions of the other macros to your question.

Comment: If BUZZER_OFF is defined like in your comment above (function-like macro), it should just work. Otherwise, you either change the macro definition or "call" the macro without `()`. I rather think it is a similar problem with `DIR_BUZ` and/or `B_BUZ_E`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33351/discussion-between-user2571585-and-undur-gongor)

Answer (score 1):

**Single-statement, function-like macros**

Please do not use curly braces (`{` and `}`) when defining single-statement macros like `DIR_IN_Tamper`.

To [safely define](http://c-faq.com/cpp/safemacros.html) a function-like macro, simply put your definition between parentheses, like this:

```
#define DIR_IN_Tamper() (FIO2DIR &= ~0X00001000)
```

Then, call your macro like this:

```
DIR_IN_Tamper();
```

It will behave like a functions which changes the value of `FIO2DIR` and then returns the changed value:

```
/* Your macro rewritten as a function.
   The return type should be the type of FIO2DIR */
uint32_t DIR_IN_Tamper()
{
    return (FIO2DIR &= ~0X00001000);
}
```

**Multi-statement, function-like macros**

If you ever need to define a multi-statement macro, see [this other C FAQ entry](http://c-faq.com/cpp/multistmt.html).

For example, define `BUZZER_OFF` as:

```
#define BUZZER_OFF() do { DIR_BUZ(); B_BUZ_E(0); } while (0)
```

Comment: Armaccess.c(973): error:  #109: expression must have (pointer-to-) function type

Comment: @user2571585: You have to remove the normal parentheses (()), not the curly braces.

Comment: @user2571585 I commented something about `{}` to your question

Comment: I have removed () braces from main..
now it looks like BUZZER_OFF;
but still error in
else

Comment: When in doubt, look at the pre-processed source: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3742822/238421.

Answer (score 0):

Macros in C are not functions. `DIR_IN_Tamper();` should be `DIR_IN_Tamper;`.

Comment: It is like this #define DIR_IN_Tamper  FIO2DIR &= ~0X00001000 
& not like u have mentioned..

Comment: Huh? I mean the call. Not the macro definition. Seems you're too much confused about C. You should get a decent C book and read it before writing code.

Comment: Then make a question about your new error, or say what error it is.

Comment: code says as follows
DIR_IN_Tamper;
  if(((IN_Tamper >> 12) & 0x01) == 1)
   BUZZER_ON;
  else
   BUZZER_OFF;
where in BUZZER_OFF is again a macro defined as
#define BUZZER_OFF { DIR_BUZ; B_BUZ_E(0); } 
since its group of statements I have used { } braces...

Comment: Mu advice is that you avoid macros in C, they're more complicated and prone to errors than you might think. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043090/why-should-i-avoid-macros-in-c) explains why.

Comment: @mOskitO   never advice any one such negative thing (avoid macros in C)


I got the answer when I started solving it myself.
I'll share it with you-
search for intermediate file in your program folder like if you have got xyz.c then search xyz.i file you will find macro expansion in there check if its there according to your logic or not.
correct in program file.