# C++ define expression evaluation

Tags: c++

Suppose we have this expression:

```
#define cube(x) x * x * x
```

And then we call it:

```
int n = 3, v;
v = cube(n + 1);   // v = 10
v = cube((n + 1)); // v = 64
v = cube(n);       // v = 27
```

So the question is: why first operation do not make `v = 64`?

Comment: Read about operator precedence. Expand the MACRO manually and check.

Comment: This must be a duplicate...

Comment: @chqrlie I suspected that but I couldn't find something similar.

Comment: Here's [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043090/why-should-i-avoid-macros-in-c). Granted it speaks about C++ since there you have mechanisms to replace the macros. But the pitfalls are the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Macros are not evaluated (*in the sense of the common interpretation of evaluation*), they are expanded at compile time.

Before the file is compiled, there is another program called the [C Preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) that replaces the macro invocation *literally*/*textually* and prepares the file for actual compilation, so for your macro

```
#define cube(x) x * x * x when you do this
```

This

```
v = cube(n + 1);
```

is replaced with this (*expaned is the correct term*)

```
v = n + 1 * n + 1 * n + 1;
// Simplifies to
v = n + n + n + 1;
// and again
v = 3 * n + 1;
```

which for `n = 3` gives you `10` exactly the observed result.

Note, that when you add parentheses

```
v = cube((n + 1));
```

then, the expansion is

```
v = (n + 1) * (n + 1) * (n + 1);
```

which is what you would expect `cube()` to do, so prevent this you should redefine your macro like this

```
#define cube(x) ((x) * (x) * (x))
```

If you are using *gcc* try

```
gcc -E source.c
```

and check the result to verify how the macro was expanded.

Comment: @iharob: good answer.  You might add a warning about potential problems with multiple evaluation.

Comment: @tomab, this is pure text substitution, which will surprise you further if you try to expand the macro with something that has side effects.

Comment: Just a nitpick: macro/textual expansion *is* a form of evaluation, although it’s not the form most people are thinking of (and, importantly, it’s no an evaluation according to C++’s rules, nor those of conventional algebra).