# Are define processed differently?

Tags: c++

Why this [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b8844efd8dbf457) give to me value "4" instead of "0"?

```
#define PLUGIN_PPQ 96
#define MIDIENGINE_SCORE_LENGTH PLUGIN_PPQ * 4

int main ()
{
    int mCurrentPatternPulse = 97;
    int patternBar = (int)floor(mCurrentPatternPulse / MIDIENGINE_SCORE_LENGTH);
    cout << "value: " << patternBar << " (" << MIDIENGINE_SCORE_LENGTH << ")";
}
```

97/384 (with/without floor) should give to me 0.

But it seems it divides by 96 instead of 384? Even if I print `MIDIENGINE_SCORE_LENGTH` is 384...

Comment: Protip: Use `constexpr` variables instead. They will be processed at compile time like the macro but will respect operator precedence because they are variables, and they are known to the language.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Other language (C instead of C++). Root cause is shared, solution isn't. C doesn't have `constexpr`.

Comment: @MSalters I don't get you. That link explains the OP's problem. You can find many C++ questions are reported as duplicated by that question like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35039313/995714). `constexpr` is a suggestion, not an answer to this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine it being a "string-replace" and not a math operation.

So `MIDIENGINE_SCORE_LENGTH`is not 384  but `96 *4`

so your code looks like:

```
floor(mCurrentPatternPulse / 96 *4 );
```

and the `mCurrentPatternPulse / 96` will be evaluated first.

Just add some brackets:

```
floor(mCurrentPatternPulse / ( MIDIENGINE_SCORE_LENGTH ) );
```

**Edit:**

Or even better put them in the define directly:

```
#define MIDIENGINE_SCORE_LENGTH ( PLUGIN_PPQ * 4 )
```

Comment: Of course, in practice, the parentheses should go into the *definition* of `MIDIENGINE_SCORE_LENGTH`, not into each and every of its uses.

Comment: @Angew ofc you're right there. Added this to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you unpick the macro, then you get

`floor(mCurrentPatternPulse / PLUGIN_PPQ * 4);`

Since `/` and `*` have the same *precedence*, evaluation is from left to right, so the expression is equivalent to

`floor((mCurrentPatternPulse / PLUGIN_PPQ) * 4)`

Note that `(mCurrentPatternPulse / PLUGIN_PPQ)` is performed in *integer arithmetic*, so any remainder is discarded prior to the multiplication.

Answer (score 5):

#defines are just text substitution.  You need to look up operator precedence.