# std::max_element skip over NANs

Tags: c++, arrays, std

I have a `std::vector<double>` that may contain several `NAN` values. I want to find the largest element in the vector. How can I efficiently skip the `NAN`s in the comparison? I'd like to avoid having to call `isnan` on each element. any ideas?

```
// std::max_element([NAN,NAN,NAN,-31,-89]) = NAN 
// because NAN > -31 returns NAN.
// how can I skip all NANs in the comparison?
// test 2 below is my use case.

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void vector_max(std::vector<double> v, double &max, int &imax){
    std::vector<double>::iterator v_iter;
    v_iter = std::max_element(v.begin(),v.end());
    imax = std::distance(v.begin(), v_iter);
    max  = *v_iter;
}

int main(){

    std::vector<double> v_vec;
    std::vector<double>::iterator v_vec_iter;
    int imax;
    double val;

    std::cout << "test 1. " << std::endl;

    v_vec.push_back( -33.0 );
    v_vec.push_back( -124.0 );
    v_vec.push_back( -31.0 );
    v_vec.push_back( 18.4 );

    vector_max(v_vec,val,imax);
    std::cout << "max(v_vec) = " << val << std::endl;
    std::cout << "indmax(v_vec) = " << imax << std::endl;

    std::cout << "test 2: my case. " << std::endl;

    v_vec.clear();
    v_vec.push_back( NAN );
    v_vec.push_back( NAN );
    v_vec.push_back( NAN );
    v_vec.push_back( -33.0 );
    v_vec.push_back( -124.0 );
    v_vec.push_back( -31.0 );
    v_vec.push_back( 31.0 );

    vector_max(v_vec,val,imax);
    std::cout << "max(v_vec) = " << val << std::endl;
    std::cout << "indmax(v_vec) = " << imax << std::endl;

};
```

this returns:

```
test 1. 
max(v_vec) = 18.4
indmax(v_vec) = 3
test 2. 
max(v_vec) = nan
indmax(v_vec) = 0
```

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here; all comparisons with NaN return `false`, so NaN can _never_ be greater (or less, or equal, etc.) than anything else. Unless you're compiling with `-ffast-math`, then NaNs are treated like 0, meaning NaN is in fact > −31.

Comment: [filter iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html) may help (even if you call `isnan` on each element).

Comment: @mindriot I wish you were right. if you care to run that piece of code, you will see that it returns what I just added at the bottom of the question.

Comment: @mindriot: Indeed. The problem here is that if !a<b and !b<a, then a and b are considered equivalent. (but not necessarily equal a==b). However, equivalence should be transitive. If 5.0 is equivalent to NaN and 3.0 is equivalent to NaN, then 3.0 is equivalent to 5.0. But 3.0 < 5.0 ! They're clearly not equivalent.

Comment: @mindriot Look at that from another angle: NaN is never less than anything and because of that max_element might return NaN. Or might not, because it is never greater than anything. Presence of NaN in sequence makes operator< not conform to strict weak ordering criteria required by all standard algorithm.

Comment: @mindriot: that is only true for equality.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot yep, see my answer.

Comment: Should have been more clear: My first comment was mostly referring to the `// because NAN > -31 returns NAN.` in the source code.

Comment: Think of NaN as an error indicator. When you have NaNs in your results something went wrong. Continuing the calculation is almost certainly the wrong thing to do when that happens. Figure out why you're getting NaNs in your results and fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
void vector_max(std::vector<double> v, double &max, int &imax){
    std::vector<double>::size_type p=0;
    imax = -1;
    max = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();

    for (auto &val : v)
    {
        if (!std::isnan(val) && val>max)
        {
            imax = p;
            max = val;
        }
        p++;
    }
}
```

Comment: accepted because of most parsimonious solution. I just replaced the `for` loop with an iterator as I can't use `auto`. thanks.

Comment: @FlorianOswald `lowest` is nicer. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 10):

You can provide a custom comparison for `max_element`:

```
void vector_max(std::vector<double> v, double &max, int &imax){
    std::vector<double>::iterator v_iter;
    v_iter = std::max_element(v.begin(),v.end(),
    [] (auto x, auto y)
    {
        return x < y ? true : isnan(x);
    });
    imax = std::distance(v.begin(), v_iter);
    max  = *v_iter;
}
```

Comment: It is a working answer, however OP stated that he wants to _"avoid having to call isnan on each element"_

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot So, this doesn't call isnan on each element, but probably most.

Comment: hey @tahsmith this is very neat. is there a way to do this without relying on C++11 features? I can't rely on those unfortunately.

Comment: @FlorianOswald, you could implement the comparison in a separate class, as per `mindriot`'s answer, but that makes it substantially less neat in my opinion

Comment: replace `x < y ? true : isnan(x)` with `not( x >= y )`. nan must always evaluate false, so for no NaN contained you basically get x<y, but with NaN x>=y evaluates false, therefore not(x>=y) returns true on NaN

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `std::max_element` uses `std::less` as its comparator by default. Depending on the order in which it processes the vector's elements, a `NAN` may appear on the right-hand side of the comparison. Since *all* comparisons with `NAN`s return `false`, this means that `NAN` can appear greater than all other elements.

Put differently, when you use `std::max_element` with the default comparator on a vector with `NAN`s, the result is actually undefined since it depends on the implementation, and on the order of elements. For example, on GCC, if I place all your `NAN`s at the *end* of the vector, I (randomly) get the desired result.

So, you have no other option than to provide your own comparison operator:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
struct NaNAwareLess
{
  bool operator () (T a, T b) const
  {
    if (std::isnan(b))
    {
      return false; // Assume NaN is less than *any* non-NaN value.
    }
    if (std::isnan(a))
    {
      return true; // Assume *any* non-NaN value is greater than NaN.
    }
    return (a < b);
  }
};

void vector_max(std::vector<double> v, double &max, int &imax){
    std::vector<double>::iterator v_iter;
    v_iter = std::max_element<std::vector<double>::iterator, NaNAwareLess<double> >(v.begin(),v.end(),NaNAwareLess<double>());
    imax = std::distance(v.begin(), v_iter);
    max  = *v_iter;
}

int main(){

    std::vector<double> v_vec;
    std::vector<double>::iterator v_vec_iter;
    int imax;
    double val;

    std::cout << "test 1. " << std::endl;

    v_vec.push_back( -33.0 );
    v_vec.push_back( -124.0 );
    v_vec.push_back( -31.0 );
    v_vec.push_back( 18.4 );

    vector_max(v_vec,val,imax);
    std::cout << "max(v_vec) = " << val << std::endl;
    std::cout << "indmax(v_vec) = " << imax << std::endl;

    std::cout << "test 2: my case. " << std::endl;

    v_vec.clear();
    v_vec.push_back( NAN );
    v_vec.push_back( NAN );
    v_vec.push_back( NAN );
    v_vec.push_back( -33.0 );
    v_vec.push_back( -124.0 );
    v_vec.push_back( -31.0 );
    v_vec.push_back( 31.0 );

    vector_max(v_vec,val,imax);
    std::cout << "max(v_vec) = " << val << std::endl;
    std::cout << "indmax(v_vec) = " << imax << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::less<double>()(NAN, -33.0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::less<double>()(-33.0, NAN) << std::endl;
};
```

I don't think you can avoid calling `isnan`.  And there's another important aspect as well: From personal experience, I found performing operations on `NAN` values to be a *lot* slower than on any other values (probably because of FPU exception handling). So, while using `isnan` might be annoying, it could also make quite a positive difference in performance.

Comment: I see, that sounds good! what's the result of comparing NAN with NAN?

Comment: The result of comparing `NAN` to `NAN` is also `false`. So the operator I used here keeps it that way.

Comment: Oh, and by the way: The more “C++” way of getting a `NAN` is using [`std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/quiet_NaN).

Comment: hey @mindriot, so you are saying i should use `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN` instead of `cmath` NAN? is it easy to explain why? thanks.

Comment: @FlorianOswald You are not _forced_ to use it at all; but there are some reasons why I prefer the `numeric_limits` variant: (1) it gives you appropriate constants for _all_ floating-point types in a clean manner, where as `cmath`'s macro constants are for specific types only. It doesn't matter so much for `NAN`, but look at `HUGE_VAL` vs. `HUGE_VALF` vs. `HUGE_VALL`, for example. (2) The C++ approach from `<limits>` _might_ be more portable (I think). …

Comment: @FlorianOswald  Some aspects that are more of a personal taste: (3) the `limits` variant “looks more like C++”, and [macros are somewhat frowned upon in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043090/why-should-i-avoid-macros-in-c). (4) You would use `<iostream>` rather than `<cstdio>` when developing in C++, so to me it makes sense to use the C++ constant from `<limits>` rather than the “old” one from `<cmath>`.

Comment: `binaray_function` is deprecated since C++11.

Comment: @black Oh, thanks, I wasn't aware of that. Will edit it out.