# Why use 0xffffffff instead of -1?

Tags: c++

I'm coming from a Java background and make my first steps in C++ graphics programming. I worked on the ogl-dev tutorials (http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/) and noticed that a macro with value `0xffffffff` is defined. I understand that it encodes -1, but what I do not understand is why I should prefer this encoding over just writing `-1`. Is it for (backwards) compatibility? Does it have to do with some idiosyncracy of C? Is it an idiom?

An example:

```
#define ERROR_VALUE 0xffffffff
```

and subsequently

```
GLuint location = glGetUniformLocation(m_shaderProg, uniformName);
    if (location == ERROR_VALUE)
        throw new exception("error happened");
```

why wouldn't I write

```
if (location == -1)
```

or define my macro as

```
#define ERROR_VALUE -1
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Semantics (to the reader of the code): -1 is a negative number, 0xffffffff is a word (probably) with all the bits set.  Without context we will have to guess.  So the question is either asking for an opinion, unclear or too broad.

Comment: x64 => -1 != 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: Overly pedantic, probably will never run into this in the wild: C++ doesn't (yet) require 2's complement integers. -1 can have other representations.

Comment: I am not sure that this represents what is considered a good C++ programming style. I had a quick look at the examples and it looks like it is more a C-oriented style of programming, using a lot of C constructs that are discouraged. If you want to learn C++, I would recommend to read https://isocpp.org/tour and https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.

Comment: Since you are new to c++, you should be aware that the C++ community generally considers the use of macros to be bad practice. We prefer to use 'const unsigned int' or 'constexpr' declarations (not available in C), because these provide type information at compile time. For some reason, many OpenGL C++ tutorials tend to shy away from C++ best practices. Maybe it's because OpenGL has a C-native API.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I know. Which makes this idiom even more obscure to me.

Comment: In two's complement, -1 will set all the bits in a number, regardless of the bit width of the container.  For example, `0xff` for `int8_t` data type results in `-1`.  However `0xff` for `int16_t` results in the value 255, not -1.

Comment: Because `#define ERROR_VALUE -1` is buggy and the code author didn't know the right way to fix it.

Comment: All that was said above is true, but if you really wanna know the code author's direction of thought, it must have been about `GLuint ` being _unsigned_, thus causing compiler warnings when being compared to negative. Despite the mentioned code problems, here it was an attempt to respect types' signedness =)

Comment: Negative 1 is only equivalent to "all bits set" in Two's complement. They're not always the same thing.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews there could be padding bits, and converting `0xff` to `int8_t` is implementation-defined, not necessarily -1

Comment: `0xffffffff` is not equal to `-1`. Its value is *always* `4294967295`, and its type is the first of `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int` that can hold that value. If assigned to a 32-bit object, it *probably* has the same representation as `-1` stored in an object of  a 32-bit signed integer type. Assign it to a 64-bit integer and you'll get `4294967295`. Literals specify values, not representations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check [the OpenGL specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) (particularly section 7.6., page 134), you will find that `glUniformLocation` is actually specified to return a `GLint`, which is a 32-Bit signed integer type. Calling `glUniformLocation` is equivalent to a call to `glGetProgramResourceLocation`, which has a return type of `GLint` as well and is specified to return the value `-1` upon error. The comparison of `location` to the `0xFFFFFFFF` put there via replacement of the `ERROR_VALUE` macro just happens to work in the tutorial code because `location` is a `GLuint` rather than a `GLint`. If `glUniformLocation` actually returns `-1` there, the `-1` will first be implicitly converted to `GLuint`. This implicit conversion will follow modulo arithmetic and the `-1` will wrap around to become `0xFFFFFFFF` since `GLuint` is a 32-Bit unsigned integer type. If `location` was of signed type instead, this would not work correctly. As has been pointed out by Nicol Bolas, if you want to compare to some constant to check for success of this function, compare the result to `GL_INVALID_INDEX` which is there for exactly this purpose. Contrary to the macro defined in the tutorial code, `GL_INVALID_INDEX` is specified to be an unsigned integer of value `0xFFFFFFFF`, which will cause any comparison to work out correctly because of the [usual arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions)…

As others have also noted in the comments above, I would not recommend that you consider the code presented in these tutorials to be representative of good C++. Using macros to define constants in particular is anything but great (see, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043090/why-should-i-avoid-macros-in-c) for more on that). We also don't normally use `new` to allocate an exception object to throw like here:

```
throw new exception("error happened");
```

In general, you'll want to avoid `new` in C++ unless you really need it (see, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new) for more on that). And if dynamic memory allocation is indeed what you need, then you'd use [RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii) ([smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one/106614#106614)) to take care of correctly handling the resource allocation…