# How '<<' operator does work with #define in C++

Tags: c++, macros, bitwise-operators

I have two operation, and I am assuming both are doing ShiftLeft bitwise operation.

```
#define TACH_MAX_OWN_ORDERS 1<<6
int myVal = 1<<6
cout<<"Value after operation|"<<myVal <<"|"<<TACH_MAX_OWN_ORDERS<<endl;
```

output of `TACH_MAX_OWN_ORDERS` value always surprise me.

```
Value after operation|64|16
```

Do anyone have any clue, how it comes???
Thanks

Comment: A macro is just a text substitution. Look at the result of `cout<<1<<6<< endl;`.

Comment: What exactly surprises you? What did you expect instead?

Comment: why it is declare in my code and using in this loop ` for(int i=0;i<TACH_MAX_OWN_ORDERS;i++)`

Answer (score 8):

Macros replace text as is, so it will result in

```
cout<<"Value after operation|"<<myVal <<"|"<<1<<6<<endl;
```

the `<<` won't result in `(int)1<<6` but rather `([...] << 1) << 6` where `[...]` will have `std::cout` at the deepest level. This means your macro will always result in 16 when used in `std::cout`, because 1 and 6 are shifted into the out stream (`"1"` + `"6"`) instead of the actual numerical value `64`.

---

You should put parantheses around the statement to avoid this:

```
#define TACH_MAX_OWN_ORDERS (1<<6)
```

---

or even better, since you [should avoid macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043090/why-should-i-avoid-macros-in-c), if available try to use compile time constants:

```
constexpr int TACH_MAX_OWN_ORDERS = 1 << 6;
```